# getting 'Bad Request' from PutAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm writing Azure Queue Trigger function app that picks up data from a message queue and upload them to a storage, that provides REST service, using PUT request. For test purpose, I'm providing test data inside request body field on Azure interface instead of picking data from the queue. I'm using PutAsJsonAsync to consume REST. The problem is I'm getting Bad Request error. I validated JSON structure using validation tool and it is valid. And I also uploaded the same data successfully using Postman. So I'm guessing it maybe that problem is in my code. Here's my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;  

public static void Run(string myQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
{
    string URL = "<url>"; 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("token","<token value>");

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PutAsJsonAsync("xxx/xx/xxx",myQueueItem).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        log.Info($"This is result: {responseString}");
    }
    else
    {
        log.Info($"Response Status Code: {response.Headers} | Reason : {response.ReasonPhrase}");
    }  


}
```

Comment: How does your myQueueItem looks like?

Comment: Just a JSON structure

Comment: Try this: client.PutAsJsonAsync("xxx/xx/xxx",new StringContent(myQueueItem, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

Comment: and try using client.PutAsync() instead of client.PutAsJsonAsync()

Comment: @Forlani : PutAync does the trick. Thanks! Could you post your reply as answer so that I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: Just did @user30646 =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `client.PutAsync()` instead of `client.PutAsJsonAsync()`

I would call it like this:

```
client.PutAsync("xxx/xx/xxx",new StringContent(myQueueItem, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result
```