# How can i consume web api in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, put

I am new to `.Net MVC`. I am trying to create a sample CRUD application using Web APIs created in `NodeJS`.

Reading data from DB(`MSSQL`) is working fine using the below code in .net MVC

```
 List<student> students = new List<student> { };
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
     students = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<student>>();
 }
```

I want to update the record in DB by consuming the node api in .net MVC. I am using the below code, but its not working,

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(
            "localhost:8082/update", data);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

student std = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<student>();
```

I want to know how can i consume a web api with PUT method.
 Any Help would be appreciated!

Comment: what error you are facing?

Comment: it is not calling the api itself

Comment: have you tried with any took like postman?

Comment: in postman, its working fine

Comment: did you check this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795476/getting-bad-request-from-putasjsonasync

Comment: here data is an object of student class. converting to string is not allowed

Comment: Where (which line) exactly has the error?  Does `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` succeed?  What is actually getting returned?  At a glance, you're expecting the updated student to be returned?  What does postman return as a response when you execute the call?